# Incrementing Array Element By One In Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am Currently working on a swift project in XCode, and I've encountered an issue where I cannot increment an array's one element by through various endeavours.

My ViewController.Swift

```
import UIKit

class FailureViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var failFactLabel: UILabel!

    let failFact = Failure()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        failFactLabel.text = failFact.failArray[0]
    }

   @IBAction func showFunFact() {   
        //this is where the issue is
    }
}
```

For the function **showFunFact**  I have previously tried

```
for var x = 0; x < failArray.cout; x++ {
    failFactLabel.text = failFact.failArray[x]
}
```

but encountered the error: "Use of Unresolved Identifier".
Putting this aside, I decided to use

```
for var x = 0; x < 10; {
       x+=1
}
```

Although this does not generate an error however, I see it stops at the first element in my array. I tried +=5 and it displays the 5th element in my array once, I believe this code runs through once. I need it to be a consistently working piece so it continuously displays the next element, I am stumped because this should theoretically work since it is called a "Loop" Any help or suggestion is Appreciated!

**Objective Redefined:**
I am trying to show one fact at a time, before this I have used a random function to generate a random fact every time however things tend to get repetitive and therefore I decided to start on the initial array index is 0 and grab the next fact (next element in array) every time the button is pressed (Thanks to Luk's Question)

Comment: well, what exactly are you trying to achieve? show only one fact at a time, a different one each touch or change through the facts rapidly automatically?

Comment: I am trying to show one fact at a time, before this I have used a random function to generate a random fact every time however things tend to get repetitive and therefore I decided to start on the initial array index is 0 and grab the next fact (next element in array) every time the button is pressed

Comment: You are using failArray in one place, failFact.failArray in another. That seems wrong.

Comment: @gnasher729 I see your logic. What do you suggest I should do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an instance variable to hold the current factIndex, if that is what you actually are trying:

```
import UIKit

class FailureViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var failFactLabel: UILabel!
    var factIndex = 0

    let failFact = Failure()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        failFactLabel.text = failFact.failArray[factIndex]
    }

   @IBAction func showFunFact() {
        factIndex++
        if factIndex >= failFact.failArray.count then {
            factIndex = 0
        }
        failFactLabel.text = failFact.failArray[factIndex]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Should I directly implement this code or should I put this into a for loop or if loop to put this into constraints?

Comment: @HenryLi that code should work as is. As I am not 100% sure what you are actually trying to achieve, try it out and then come back and tell me if that is what you desired or try to explain what should happen instead.

Comment: @HenryLi I already added/delcared the factIndex for you - I am guessing you added it inside `showFunFact` - please take a closer look at my solution, I added the factIndext in the 6th line. It has to have class/object level scope and has to be defined outside the method.

Comment: works like a charm! Do you suggest adding an if statement like if(factindex<failarray.count) {failFactLabel.text = failFact.failArray[factIndex] }

Comment: My mistake previously, I am a clumsy person.

Comment: @HenryLi yes, or you could set the factIndex to 0 after it exceeds the bounds, this would cause your facts to loop and start again from the beginning if you happen to click this often.

Comment: @HenryLi I included a sample solution for that case in the answer as well.

Comment: I see that whenever I declare factArray.count, it reports an error use of unresolved identifier, why is this?

Comment: Hmm? Self.factIndex = 0?

Comment: @HenryLi are you using my exact `showFunFact` code? I have to go in a meeting now - I hope that already answered your question so far

Comment: Thanks for putting up with my absolute clumsiness, need to fix this personal issue for coding. Otherwise after a few tweaks on my own this code works like a charm, handles the constraint. You sir deserves a major thanks from my side. Stackoverflow is lucky to have you thanks!

Comment: Hello  @luk2302  i have   also a similar issue but The value i am getting is dynamic [ array which cosisting  10 Dictionary and each Dictionary is having an array ] and i want to increase the index on action . Parsing is done and i am to Display the First Index of that array by setting the index but not  able to increase The Index . Any help will be appriciated, Thanks.

Comment: @AvinashMishra difficult to help in comments alone, please post an actual question and Link it here. That way I can maybe help you seeing your code and exactly what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @luk2302 Here is My Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842704/how-to-increase-index-of-array-when-the-value-is-dynamic-swift Thanks