# How To increase index of Array when the value is Dynamic (Swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am Getting a Dynamic Array which Consist (Dictionary with Array ) and want to increase the Index of Array and will go on to Next Dictionary on action.

After Parsing The Value in swapLibs

```
var currentQuizIndex = 0
func Dataparsed() {
    ServiceManager.service(ServiceType.POST, path: urslStr, param: nil, completion: {  (sucess, response, error, code) -> Void in
        if (code == 200) {
            let QuizData  = (swapLibs?.valueForKey("quiz") as! NSArray)
            let  quizData = playInfo.PlayQuizInfo(QuizData[self.currentQuizIndex] as? NSDictionary)
            self.playQuizArray.addObject(quizData)
            self.playQuizTitle?.text = quizData.quizQuestion
            self.playQImage.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: quizData.quizQImage!))
            self.QNumber?.text = "\(self.Qno)/\(self.noofQuestion)"
        }
    })
}
```

And The Modal is

```
class playInfo: NSObject {

    var quizId :           String? = ""
    var quizQId :          String? = ""
    var quizQImage :       String? = ""
    var quizQuestion :     String? = ""
    var quizType :         String? = ""
    var quizIndex :        String? = ""


    class func  PlayQuizInfo(dict: NSDictionary?) -> playInfo {

        let Pinfo = playInfo()
        Pinfo.WrapPlayQuiz(dict)
        return Pinfo
    }

    func WrapPlayQuiz(dict: NSDictionary?)  {
        if dict == nil {
            return
        }
        self.quizId           = dict!.objectForKey("quizId")    as? String
        self.quizIndex        = dict!.objectForKey("index")     as? String
        self.quizQImage       = dict!.objectForKey("QuesImage")     as? String
        self.quizQuestion     = dict!.objectForKey("question")  as? String
        self.quizType         = dict!.objectForKey("Type")      as? String
        self.quizQId          = dict!.objectForKey("questionId")      as? String
    }

}
```

Here is Structure

```
{  
   "quiz":[  
      {  
         "quizId":"7295",
         "QuesImage":"http:\/\/proprofs.com\/api\/ckeditor_images\/man-approaches-woman1(1).jpg",
         "question":"How do you know him?",
         "questionId":"216210",
         "Type":"PQ",
         "index":4,
         "keys":[  
            {  
               "answerId":"8266",
               "option":"He's in one or more of my classes, and we're good friends.",
               "AnsImage":"Image Not Available"
            },
            {  },
            {  },
            {  },
            {  }
         ]
      },
      {  },
      {  },
      {  },
      {  },
      {  },
      {  },
      {  },
      {  },
      {  },
      {  },
      {  }
   ]
}
```

Each Dictionary is Containing same Key As above

Any Help Will Be Appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the response structure?

Comment: Do comment here if you update your question.

Comment: @Mr.UB You may Check it.Thanks

Comment: So you are not using `keys`? And you want to fill `playQuizArray` with all the data from the `quiz ` array in response?

Comment: not able to store keys coz it is an array what will be the way to store it ? by declaring an Array ?@Mr.UB.

Comment: all dictionary stored in array so just navigate through array and fetch dictionary

Comment: @Mr.UB can You please have a look. Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39241987/inside-datataskwithrequest-is-not-executing-in-swift-while-hitting-the-api?noredirect=1#comment65821583_39241987

Comment: @Mr.UB  please Have A look  Thanks.

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari  please Have A look  Thanks.

Comment: Ping me in the group

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: can We have a Chat please.? @Mr.UB

Comment: @Mr.UB Quiestion is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849611/how-to-push-vc-from-custom-collcetionviewcell-which-is-on-tableviewcell-ios-swif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I don't have `ServiceManager` at my end so I have created this code hypothetically. It might solve you issue of saving all data in to one array. It also adds keys in to array as an object.

EDIT 1 : correct QuizKey object array formation. Let me know if any kind of error occurs, as I am unable to test it at my end.

Edit 2: I have made a general ViewController its working perfectly.Try running this View Controller file and you will see the results.

```
class TestVC: UIViewController {

    //An Array similar to the response you are getting from the server
    var response:[AnyObject] = [
        [
            "quizId" : "1111",
            "QuesImage" : "http://proprofs.com/api/ckeditor_images/man-approaches-woman1(1).jpg",
            "question" : "How do you know him?",
            "questionId" : "216210",
            "Type" : "PQ",
            "index" : 4,
            "keys":[
                [
                    "answerId":"8266",
                    "option":"He's in one or more of my classes, and we're good friends.",
                    "AnsImage":"Image Not Available"
                ],
                [
                    "answerId":"8266",
                    "option":"He's in one or more of my classes, and we're good friends.",
                    "AnsImage":"Image Not Available"
                ],
                [
                    "answerId":"8266",
                    "option":"He's in one or more of my classes, and we're good friends.",
                    "AnsImage":"Image Not Available"
                ]
            ]
        ],
        [
            "quizId" : "2222",
            "QuesImage" : "http://proprofs.com/api/ckeditor_images/man-approaches-woman1(1).jpg",
            "question" : "How do you know him?",
            "questionId" : "216210",
            "Type" : "PQ",
            "index" : 4,
            "keys":[
                [
                    "answerId":"8266",
                    "option":"He's in one or more of my classes, and we're good friends.",
                    "AnsImage":"Image Not Available"
                ],
                [
                    "answerId":"8266",
                    "option":"He's in one or more of my classes, and we're good friends.",
                    "AnsImage":"Image Not Available"
                ],
                [
                    "answerId":"8266",
                    "option":"He's in one or more of my classes, and we're good friends.",
                    "AnsImage":"Image Not Available"
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]

    var playQuizArray:[playInfo]! = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(response)

        for dict in response {
            self.playQuizArray.append(playInfo.PlayQuizInfo(dict as? [String:AnyObject]))
        }

        print(self.playQuizArray)

        let quiz = self.playQuizArray[0]
        print("quizId \(quiz.quizId)")
        print("keyAnswerId \(quiz.quizKeys![0].keyAnswerId)")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}

class playInfo: NSObject {
    var quizId :           String? = ""
    var quizQId :          String? = ""
    var quizQImage :       String? = ""
    var quizQuestion :     String? = ""
    var quizType :         String? = ""
    var quizIndex :        String? = ""
    //quizKeys will contain quiz array
    var quizKeys :       [QuizKey]? = []

    class func  PlayQuizInfo(dict: [String:AnyObject]?) -> playInfo {

        let Pinfo = playInfo()
        Pinfo.WrapPlayQuiz(dict)
        return Pinfo
    }

    func WrapPlayQuiz(dict: [String:AnyObject]?)  {
        if dict == nil {
            return
        }
        self.quizId           = dict!["quizId"] as? String
        self.quizIndex        = dict!["index"] as? String
        self.quizQImage       = dict!["QuesImage"] as? String
        self.quizQuestion     = dict!["question"] as? String
        self.quizType         = dict!["Type"] as? String
        self.quizQId          = dict!["questionId"] as? String

        //add key object array to the quizKeys
        if let arrKeys = dict!["keys"] as? [AnyObject] {
            for arr in arrKeys {
                let key:QuizKey = QuizKey.QuizKeyInfo(arr as? [String : AnyObject])
                self.quizKeys?.append(key)
            }
        }
    }

}

class QuizKey: NSObject {
    var keyAnswerId :       String? = ""
    var keyOption :         String? = ""
    var keyAnsImage :       String? = ""

    class func  QuizKeyInfo(dict: [String:AnyObject]?) -> QuizKey {
        let QKeys = QuizKey()
        QKeys.WrapQuizKeys(dict)
        return QKeys
    }

    func WrapQuizKeys(dict: [String:AnyObject]?)  {
        if dict == nil {
            return
        }

        self.keyAnswerId      = dict!["answerId"]    as? String
        self.keyOption        = dict!["option"]     as? String
        self.keyAnsImage      = dict!["AnsImage"]     as? String
    }

}
```

Comment: working Fine @Mr.UB  could you please let Me know how to increase Index on Action or Button Pressed .By the way Thanks. For effort

Comment: Getting Dict in append(Key) in next qkeys.wrapQuizKeys(Dict) got nil

Comment: you mean this line? `QKeys.WrapQuizKeys(dict)`

Comment: done the edit u did worked. Thanks .   One More Thing can You tell me which array should i return on table view and how to return it coz i have to show label and Image on Cell

Comment: return `playQuizArray ` coz it contains are the data and you have to fetch data using : `let quiz = playQuizArray [indexPath.row]` and get values like `cell.textLabel.text = quiz.quizQuestion`

Comment: dispalyd the Question . but a question having Dynamic Option Value so  for Ans Option what Should I return ?

Comment: ya no Of Option varries according to Question.

Comment: want to Show optionon onTableView

Comment: you can access option using: `let options = quiz.quizKeys `, and for displaying it , i think you have to look for table section , where each question will be a section and options will be rows under the sections, depending upon the number of options per question.

Comment: let quiz = self.playArray[0]  return (quiz.quizKeys?.count)!  as it is in numberOfRowsInSection it GIves  Crash and error is fatal error: Index out of range. Thanks Please Have A look.

Comment: Hi @Mr.UB i am in a new problem Please help . it is With COREDATA where i have to Delete A row  (on Action) but data is in VC Not TVC . please help

Comment: Have you posted a new question?

Comment: I am Not Able to Post a Question it says That  You have reached your question limit
Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. Can I Post The Question From Other AC.@Mr.UB

Comment: Ask SO, why they blocked you. This should not happen.I think its because you are asking question on comments.http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Comment: I have Posted A QUESTION HAVE A LOOK thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39609840/how-do-i-find-and-delete-row-from-coredata-value-is-on-vc-not-tablevc-ios-swift