# How to parse JSON data with the same key and different data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, swift

I have a little problem with parse JSON data.

There have a Web API，basic response data like this:

```
{
    topic_name: "Kevin",
    topic_type: 1,
    extraData: {}
}
```

With the different `topic_type` value, the `extraData` maybe have different data structure, e.g the `extraData` object has different key-values.

In this case, how to create model classes and parse the JSON string to models?

Or does this API design reasonable? Is there a better API design to solve these cases?

update 1:

With the same `topic_type`, the `extraData`'s structure is always same.

I have considered use subclasses, but it need a subclass for every `topic_type`.

update 2:

Here is some example of JSON data, different `topic_type` with different `extraData`.

when topic_type equal to 1,

```
{
    topic_name: "Kevin",
    topic_type: 1,
    extraData: {
        data_type1: value,
        data_type2: value2
    }
}
```

when topic_type equal to 2,

```
{
    topic_name: "David",
    topic_type: 2,
    extraData: {
        data_type3: value3
    }
}
```

it not real data, I'm not deal with a 'topic' issue, just a example, the key is the `extraData` object has different type keys.

Comment: Do you know the extra fields that you are getting for each topic_type? Are they always the same for each topic_type? You can decide between subclassing or use only one class.

Comment: This post will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842704/how-to-increase-index-of-array-when-the-value-is-dynamic-swift/38844338#38844338

Comment: can you show some examples for different data models for extraData ?

Comment: @UmairAfzal updated. Thank you.

Comment: @crom87 yes, same `topic_type` always has same `extraData` structure.

Comment: Use ObjectMapper and model your JSON, if data exists it will model it and if there is no data it will not throw any error so you are good to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSONModel](https://github.com/jsonmodel/jsonmodel) might be exactly what you're looking for. Parses json and gives you models

Comment: I know this awesome project, in my impression this project only can parse static model type with static JSON structure, in my case, the `extraData`'s structure is dynamic depend on `topic_type`. Does JSONModel work with this issue?

Comment: You could create an extraData model that has optional properties and it should create the extraData model with the content you're looking for. I've used it in the past for models with changing content from the json

Comment: Do you mean create a extraModel with all possible keys?

Comment: Yes or make 2 different models and look to generate the different ones based on the topic_type

Comment: If only create one extraData model, the model will has to many useless keys and all of them equal to nil, maybe it's a bit ugly?

Comment: And if create too or more model class, when use this `topic` model, which type of `extraData` property to use is a problem.

Comment: Surely you would create different methods for processing the different topic_type? Then the model you're using would match up with the content you received. Based on the topic type you would know what properties are present and can be used

Comment: With this solution , it's not longer need to create a massive extraData model, but create some different extraData model, and create diff type of properties, depend on `topic_type`'s value, when use the model, use correct extraData model type of property.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I was saying

Answer (score 0):

try to define all types in a class:

```
{
    topic_name: "Kevin",
    topic_type: 1,
    extraData: {
        data_type1: value,
        data_type2: value2,
        data_type3: value3,
    }
}
```

after Json parsing, take the data types u need based on topic type.

Ps. All data types need to be nullable