# How to push VC from Custom CollectionViewCell Which is on TableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am Having a `tableView` and Cell, on Cell i have a `collectionView` and Displaying Some Content On it .

I want to send a link on selection of `indexPath`.

I want to push/present  My View from Custom `CollectionViewCell` which is on `TableViewCell`.

```
class secondTopicTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var relatedCustom: UICollectionView!
    var relArray  = NSArray()
     func loadArray(arr: NSArray) {
        self.relArray = arr
        self.relatedCustom.reloadData()
    }
}

extension secondTopicTableViewCell : UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return relArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("collection", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! relatedCollectionViewCell
        let info = self.relArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! specificTopicInfo
        cell.showInfo(info)
        return cell
    }
}



extension secondTopicTableViewCell : UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let relatedTopic =  self.relArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)  as! specificTopicInfo

        let str  = relatedTopic.relatedLink!
        print(str)
    }
}



class relatedCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var relatedLabel: UILabel!

    func showInfo(info: specificTopicInfo) {
        relatedLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        relatedLabel.text = info.relatedTitle
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `class secondTopicTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
        class secondTopicTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {` ? TWICE!

Comment: @Mr.UB it was a Mistake Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to navigate using **didSelectItemAtIndexPath** same as Tableview control.
Write your Navigation code to **didSelectItemAtIndexPath** of Collectionview

Comment: When i  wirite a code Inside didSelectItemAtIndexPath it says TableViewCell Has no Mamber of Cell Class

Comment: Please refer : [link](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are nesting a collection view inside a table view cell and want to trigger an action from the table view displaying this 1st cell, you can do two things.

#### First

You can use the UICollectionViewDelegate protocol to catch the user interaction with your collection view cell.

Don't forget to set your table view cell as the delegate of its collection view.

#### Second

You can create your own protocol (useful when a cell have multiple buttons).

Then, each button will have its own “didTap” method, instead of the “didSelect” method from the original collection view delegate.